# Python dataset in web application

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, bottle

I wrote a simple REST API with pybottle as web framework and [dataset](http://dataset.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) as database handler. I wonder about how dataset handles (opens and closes) connections to the database and how far I would need to take care about this.

Consider the following:

```
db = dataset.connect('sqlite:///database.db')
table = db['table']

def some_function():
    # do some manipulation (eg. insert) in 'table'
```

what happens when I call `some_function()` from the web application (which is in another file)? Does dataset open and close the connection to the database properly after the execution of the function? Or do I have a new open connection with every function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every SQL driver in Python follows the [Python DB API PEP0249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).
As far as I see you are using a driver for SQLite so it should follow the same rules.

SQLAlchemy has a built-in way to establish a long lasting connection and avoid connection drop. You can create a method `get_connection()` that returns a `Database` object or restablishes connection if there is no active one.

Check the `connect` [documentation](https://dataset.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html) and [source code](https://dataset.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/dataset.html#connect) to see how the library wraps the communication with the database.

Comment: Thank you for your response! However I did not clearly understand whether the code snippet above would be fine or not. What would happen if multiple users call `some_function()` concurrently in the web application? Would one database manipulation wait until the other has finished? Do the connections close automatically after the write operation? Do I need to change anything in my code snippet?

Comment: @wildthing `some_function` does not open a connection in your code. It's done at module level (outside function). SQLAlchemy checks if a connection is already in place, if true uses the current connection else establishes a new one. Every operation uses the same connection, it's not advisable to manually open/close it, the connection just keeps being there. See SQLAlchemy documentation that explains how connections are handled.